How to run test on a single thread via Kotlin coroutines?
I have a class and a test. I want to execute all coroutines on a single thread. The test currently fails:
class MainClass {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)
    var value = 0

    fun run() {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(1000)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    delay(1000)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        value = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestTest {
    @Test
    fun test() = runTest {
        val test = MainClass()
        test.run()
        assertTrue(test.value == 1)
    }
}

How can I make the test pass?

But Dispatchers.IO & Dispatchers.Main must'n be edited.

Ideally, you should be injecting your dispatchers, specifically so you can override them in unit tests.

"But Dispatchers.IO & Dispatchers.Main must'n be edited."  You can't have that and what you ask for in this question.  You must either change your dispatchers, or give up on single-threaded tests.

Why would you even want that in the first place?  The idea of a unit test is to ensure it will work in the real world.  The purpose of the run function in your code is to do things on other threads/coroutines.  Not testing that would seem to make the test pointless, it might still not work the way you want in the real world.

The problem is that you launch a coroutine in run, but in your test you try to access its result (value = 1) before the coroutine completes.
This is a common problem when testing asynchronous code. The solution is to use a TestDispatcher that uses virtual time, so you can let the coroutine execute in a controlled manner, like progressing step by step or fast-forwarding it.
That means you need to use different dispatchers in your test than the ones you hardcoded in MainClass. This is the main reason why you should inject your dispatchers instead:
class MainClass(
    val dispatcherIO: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
) {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)
    var value = 0

    fun run() {
        scope.launch(dispatcherIO) {
            delay(1000)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                withContext(dispatcherIO) {
                    delay(1000)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        value = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This code behaves the same as the code from your question, but the test can now supply a different IO dispatcher. Dispatchers.Main is still hardcoded. The reason for that is that the main dispatcher is handled a bit differently in tests. There is a special way to replace the main dispatcher during runtime, so only the IO dispatcher needs to be made variable.
The test would now look like this:
class TestTest {
    @Test
    fun test() = runTest {
        val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)

        try {
            val test = MainClass(testDispatcher)
            test.run()
            advanceUntilIdle()
            assertTrue(test.value == 1)
        } finally {
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
    }
}

testDispatcher is the dispatcher that is now used. First it is passed to Dispatchers.setMain() to replace the Main dispatcher. Then it is also passed to the constructor of MainClass so it is also used as the IO dispatcher. You could use different TestDispatchers here, but I don't see a reason to do that for your current code.
The actual test code is now wrapped by a try block that is needed to reset the main dispatcher afterwards. Usually you would use a JUnit test rule to set and reset the Main dispatcher, though, to keep the test code clear from the setup logic. See here for more: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#setting-main-dispatcher
So far the changes only applied to the setup of your test. The only change you have to make to your actual test logic is the line advanceUntilIdle(): After launching the coroutine with test.run() this now suspends the current code until all coroutines on the testScheduler are finished. So when you test in the next line for test.value == 1 this will now actually be true and your test passes successfully.
